# there exists set $A=\{n_{1},n_{2},\cdots,n_{k}\},k\ge 4,n_{k}\in N^{+}$, such that $a_{n_{1}},a_{n_{2}},\cdots,a_{n_{k}}$ be an arithmetic sequence？

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$a_{n}=3\cdot 2^{n-1}+3n-2,n\ge 1$$

Question:

> there exists  set $A=\{n_{1},n_{2},\cdots,n_{k}\},k\ge 4,n_{k}\in N^{+}$, such that
>   $a_{n_{1}},a_{n_{2}},\cdots,a_{n_{k}}$ be an arithmetic sequence？

I guess it exists,
because $$a_{n_{i}}-a_{n_{i-1}}=3\cdot 2^{n_{i}-1}-3\cdot 2^{n_{i-1}-1}+3(n_{i}-n_{i-1})=constant$$
take $n_{i}-n_{i-1}=k_{i}$
we have
$$a_{n_{i}}-a_{n_{i-1}}=3\cdot 2^{n_{i-1}-1}[2^{k_{i}}-1]+3k_{i}=constant$$

Comment: Can you answer the question of whether there is a 4-term arithmetic progression in the sequence $a_n=2^n$? I suspect if you can answer that question, you can answer the one you want to answer.

Comment: at least 4 term

Comment: I don't understand your comment, abandon; do you understand mine?

Comment: sorry,I don't understand you comment

Comment: Let $b_n=2^n$. Do there exist four (or more) terms in this sequence that are in arithmetic progression? If you can answer my question, I have a feeling you will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Oh,I have prove it,can't exist

Comment: Good! Write it up, and post it as an answer.